# Find the roots of simple linear regression confidence interval

Tags: r, optimization, linear-regression

I am working on finding the roots of confidence interval of simple linear regression. WLOG, we can focus on lower confidence interval.

Question:
How to find the roots of simple linear regression confidence interval or is there any function in R (or source) that solve this problem?

Thought:

First, we can recognize the confidence interval of simple linear regression is a quadratic function. This implies two things:

1. There are at most two complex roots
2. There is closed-form solution

With this in mind, I can think of three potential solutions:

1. use `uniroot` to find the solution. Unfortunately, this requires strong prior knowledge to define `interval` arguemnt.
2. Use closed-form solution. This is pretty straight forward for this problem but I am leaning toward solution through optimization. (unless it is already implement somewhere in R)
3. optimization, the general idea is as follow:

   Step 1. use `optim` to find minimum/maximum

   Step 2. use `uniroot` to find the potential root from left and right of the minimum/maximum

   maybe I can incorporate some information from value/ gradient to speed up the process?

Example:

```
fit <- lm(qsec~mpg,data=mtcars)

prediction <- function(newvalue,lm_model,name){
  
  predictdata <- data.frame(newvalue)
  names(predictdata) <- name
  
  pred <- predict(lm_model,newdata=predictdata,interval = "confidence")%>%
    as.data.frame
  return(pred$lwr)
}



uniroot(prediction,interval=c(-100,100),lm_model=fit,name="mpg")$root

[1] -59.30344
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much speed do you need? Do you need to do this process thousands or millions of times?  On my system running your code takes about 0.012 seconds, including the fit itself ...

Here's another approach - construct the lower confidence interval over a wide range (in this case I'm going from the mean down to 20SD below the mean) and use linear approximation to find the (approximate) root. (This takes about 0.003 seconds; I haven't bothered benchmarking.)

```r
r <- with(mtcars, mean(mpg) + c(0, -20*sd(mpg)))
rvec <- seq(r[1], r[2], length.out = 501)
p <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(mpg = rvec),
             interval = "confidence")
approx(p[, "lwr"], rvec, xout = 0)$y
```

-59.3034

Comment: Thank you! Speed is not an issue since I am working on small dataset (max 1k record). I am more concerning with finding all reasonable solutions. Your -20 SD approach certainly inspires me!